# How do I setup a route to capture all subsequent URL segments after the controller as a parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to setup a route of the following form (like in an HTTP handler)

Controller/ * / * / * /* (to any arbitrary depth)

I'm new to MVC routes but I want to setup a route where basically it's like

MyController/{UrlSegments}

So for instance MyController/assets/images/logo.png would goto MyController and pass "assets/images/logo.png" as a parameter to the route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set up your route mapping like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{*stuff}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "DefaultAction" }
);
```

Then when you hit

```
/Default/one/two/three/four
```

It will hit the DefaultAction on the DefaultController and you will need a string parameter called stuff that will have a value of

```
one/two/three/four
```

Comment: The routes should always work from the root of the app, not the root of the website, so you shouldn't have to change anything to make it work from a virtual directory